# Nodejs MySQL connection query return value to function call

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying get value from database. Trying it out with a demo example. But I am having problem to synchronize the calls, tried using callback function. I am beginner in node.js, so don't know if this is the right way.

FILE 1 : app.js

```
var data;

var db = require('./db.js');

var query = 'SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution';

var r = db.demo(query, function(result) { data = result; });

console.log( 'Data : ' + data);
```

FILE 2 : db.js

```
var mysql      = require('./node_modules/mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
});

module.exports.demo = function(queryString, callback) {
    try {
        connection.connect();
        console.log('Step 1');

        connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
            console.log('Step 2');
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR : " + err);
            }
            console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);

            callback(rows[0].solution);

            return rows[0].solution;
        });
        callback();

        connection.end();
        console.log('Step 3');
    }
    catch(ex) {
        console.log("EXCEPTION : " + ex);
    }
};
```

OUTPUT :

```
Step 1
Step 3
Data : undefined
Step 2
The solution is:  2
```

Referred to this question also, but it didnt solve my problem :
[nodeJS return value from callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651046/nodejs-return-value-from-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
var r = db.demo(query, function(result) { data = result; });

console.log( 'Data : ' + data);
```

The `console.log` will run before the callback function gets called, because `db.demo` is asynchronous, meaning that it might take some time to finish, but all the while the next line of the code, `console.log`, will be executed.

If you want to access the results, you need to wait for the callback function to be called:

```
var r = db.demo(query, function(result) { 
  console.log( 'Data : ' + result);
});
```

This is how most code dealing with I/O will function in Node, so it's important to learn about it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its executing the way it should, but i have a doubt, by using the above approach we can only perform actions on result we got in the scope of the callback function, right..?

Comment: if i want to perform action on data after the function call wil it work..?

Comment: No, it won't, but that's how Node works. There are libraries which mitigate this sort of workflow, like [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: can I use await like  var r = await db.demo(query, function(result) { data = result; });

Comment: @FarhatAziz no, `db.demo()` is not async and doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

in a file db.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  user: process.env.SQL_USER,
  host: process.env.SQL_HOST,
  database: process.env.SQL_DB,
  password: process.env.SQL_PSWD,
  port: 3306,
});

async function connect() {
  try {
    await con.connect();
    console.log("Connected to MySql!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

module.exports = { connect };
```

Then in another file index.js

```js
const db = require("./data/db");

db.connect();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).