# Change outside value from inside javascript function (using with expressjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to authorize a user to perform a specific task using expressjs. The problem is if the value I assign inside an inline function can't be kept when it leaves the function.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'database'
});

exports.authorizeAndWriteToSession = function (req, res, resource_code, right) {
    req.session.authorized = false;

    if (!req.session.authenticated) {
        res.send("Không có quyền truy cập tài nguyên này vì chưa đăng nhập");
    }
    else {
        if (!req.session.validated) {
            res.send("");
        }
        else {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM role_based_acl...', [req.session.user_id, resource_code], function (err, rows) {
                    if (rows.length === 0) {
                        res.send("<h2 style='color:red'></h2>");
                    }
                    else {
                        if (right === 'view') {
                            req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_view === 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (right === 'list') {
                                req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_list === 1);
                            }
                            else {
                                if (right === 'retrieve') {
                                    req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_view === 1);
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (right === 'create') {
                                        req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_create === 1);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (right === 'update') {
                                            req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_update === 1);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            if (right === 'delete') {
                                                req.session.authorized = (rows[0].allow_delete === 1);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                connection.release();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

I've never been able to get `res.session.authorized` with true value.

Comment: When leaving which function?

Comment: Hi Edgar, it's the connection.query function.

Comment: May someone help? I was stuck here for a long time

Comment: Well, I've found these topics. I'm wondering I can't neither reuse values from a function or solve my problem except I quit nodejs :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651046/nodejs-return-value-from-callback
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635791/nodejs-mysql-connection-query-return-value-to-function-call